# How do I delete most keys in a json file using python?

Tags: python, json, twitterapi-python

I have a json file with all the data I searched using Twitter API. I only want to keep certain keys in that file and delete the rest of them, but don't know how to do it correctly. I wrote some code to do so, but I get the error "list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
import json

def read_json(json_file:str)->list:
    tweets_data=[]
    for tweet in open(json_file, 'r'):
        tweets_data.append(json.loads(tweet))
    return tweets_data
tags = ["created_at", "full_text"]
tweet_list=read_json('test.json')

for i in tweet_list["tweet"].keys():
    if i not in tags:
        del tweet_list["tweet"][i]
        
print (tweet_list[0])
```

Comment: please provide sample input and desire output

Comment: You may take a look at the differences between a list and a key-value container, like a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def read_json(json_file:str)->list:
    tweets = []
    with open(json_file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            tweets.append(json.loads(line))
    return tweets
tags = ['created_at', 'full_text']
tweets = read_json('tweets.json')
for tweet in tweets:
    for key in list(tweet.keys()):
        if key not in tags:
            del tweet[key]
```

Answer (score 1):

You've gotten really close to something working, but have a bug in the filtering section.

Your `read_json()` function returns a [python list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists), which is assigned to `tweet_list`.

The error message refers to `tweet_list['tweet']`, and says that you must use integers or pairs of numbers (slices) to select from within a list. Not a string `tweet`.

If you change your code to use the number `0`

```
for i in tweet_list[0].keys():
    if i not in tags:
        del tweet_list[0][i]
```

It will filter out the unwanted tags from the **first** element in the list.

To filter every element in the list, you need to iterate over all them with aother for loop.

```
for i in range(tweet_list):
    for key in tweet_list[i].keys():
        if key not in tags:
            del tweet_list[i][key]
```